# Go: Not running on powerpc64 (big-endian)

Tags: go, installation, elf, powerpc

I have downloaded the GO package(ppc64) for the PowerPC 64 machine.When I run the go it throws the following error:

```
./go: line 1:ELF▒9@p@8: not found
./go: line 2: syntax error: unexpected ")"
```

Machine information is like below,

```
uname -a
Linux 0005B9427C4C 3.12.19-rt30 #1 SMP Sun Jul 2 16:21:28 IST 2017 ppc64 GNU/Linux
```

From /proc/cpuinfo:
    processor       : 0
    cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
    clock           : 1599.999984MHz
    revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

```
processor       : 1
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

processor       : 2
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

processor       : 3
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

processor       : 4
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

processor       : 5
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

processor       : 6
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

processor       : 7
cpu             : e6500, altivec supported
clock           : 1599.999984MHz
revision        : 2.0 (pvr 8040 0120)

timebase        : 41666666
platform        : CoreNet Generic
model           : fsl,B4860QDS
```

I have downloaded the go1.8.3.linux-ppc64le.tar.gz package from https://golang.org/dl/.

I have searched a lot but could not find any solution. Can you tell me what is going wrong?How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel reports the `ppc64` architecture.  This means it is 64-bit POWER in *big endian* mode.  The Go project only publishes `ppc64le` (64-bit POWER in *little endian* mode) builds: [Go stable downloads](https://golang.org/dl/#stable) only offers a `go1.8.3.linux-ppc64le.tar.gz` download.

The Go sources contain a 64-bit POWER big-endian port, but you need to compile it yourself.  (But this is definitely off the beaten path, so you might run into issues.)  Note that Go 1.9 will require POWER8 even in big-endian mode, so depending on the hardware you have, even a self-compiled version could be a dead-end.  (`e6500` in the `/proc/cpuinfo` output suggests that this platform is *not* POWER8-compatibile.)

Another option is the GCC Go compiler (`gccgo`).  This Go compiler will work with many GCC targets, and the chances are good that it will remain supported to some degree in the foreseeable future.  However, few Go programmers care about `gccgo`, so you might encounter packages which do not work with it.

Comment: So how to get package for big endian?Or how to cross compile?

Comment: You should perhaps add `/proc/cpuinfo` contents to your question. If it doesn't show POWER8, I don't think it's worth the effort because Go 1.9 will stop working anyway.

Comment: I have add the /proc/cpuinfo information in the question.From your answer it seems like i can't install go on my machine.Can we have some other way?

Comment: Seems like `gccgo` is your only long-term option then.